# How to find the image processed image file from javascript and view in specific loaction?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ImageUploader = function(config) {
    if (!config || (!config.inputElement) || (!config.inputElement.getAttribute) || config.inputElement.getAttribute('type') !== 'file') {
        throw new Error('Config object passed to ImageUploader constructor must include "inputElement" set to be an element of type="file"');
    }
    this.setConfig(config);

    var This = this;
    this.config.inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var fileArray = [];
        var cursor = 0;
        for (; cursor < This.config.inputElement.files.length; ++cursor) {
            fileArray.push(This.config.inputElement.files[cursor]);
        }
        This.progressObject = {
            total : parseInt(fileArray.length, 10),
            done : 0,
            currentItemTotal : 0,
            currentItemDone : 0
        };
        if (This.config.onProgress) {
            This.config.onProgress(This.progressObject);
        }
        This.handleFileList(fileArray, This.progressObject);
    }, false);

    if (This.config.debug) {
        console.log('Initialised ImageUploader for ' + This.config.inputElement);
    }

};

ImageUploader.prototype.handleFileList = function(fileArray) {
    var This = this;
    if (fileArray.length > 1) {
        var file = fileArray.shift();
        this.handleFileSelection(file, function() {
            This.handleFileList(fileArray);
        });
    } else if (fileArray.length === 1) {
        this.handleFileSelection(fileArray[0], function() {
            if (This.config.onComplete) {
                This.config.onComplete(This.progressObject);
            }
        });
    }
};

ImageUploader.prototype.handleFileSelection = function(file, completionCallback) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    this.currentFile = file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var This = this;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;

        img.onload = function(){
            This.scaleImage(img, completionCallback);
        }

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

ImageUploader.prototype.scaleImage = function(img, completionCallback) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    while (canvas.width >= (2 * this.config.maxWidth)) {
        canvas = this.getHalfScaleCanvas(canvas);
    }

    if (canvas.width > this.config.maxWidth) {
        canvas = this.scaleCanvasWithAlgorithm(canvas);
    }

    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', this.config.quality);
 this.performUpload(imageData, completionCallback);
 /* 
  img = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "script.php",
     data: { 
     imgBase64: imageData
     }
   }).done(function(o) {
     console.log('saved'); 
   });
 */
 

};


ImageUploader.prototype.performUpload = function(imageData, completionCallback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var This = this;
    var uploadInProgress = true;
    var headers = this.config.requestHeaders;
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        uploadInProgress = false;
        This.uploadComplete(e, completionCallback);
    };
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
        This.progressUpdate(e.loaded, e.total);
    }, false);
    xhr.open('POST', this.config.uploadUrl, true);
    
    if(typeof headers === 'object' && headers !== null) {
        Object.keys(headers).forEach(function(key,index) {
            if(typeof headers[key] !== 'string') {
                var headersArray = headers[key];
                for(var i = 0, j = headersArray.length; i < j; i++) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headersArray[i]);
                }   
            } else {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);                
            }
        });
    }
    
    xhr.send(imageData.split(',')[1]);

    if (this.config.timeout) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (uploadInProgress) {
                xhr.abort();
                This.uploadComplete({
                    target: {
                        status: 'Timed out' 
                    }
                }, completionCallback);
            }
        }, this.config.timeout);
    }
    
    if (this.config.debug) {
        var resizedImage = document.createElement('img');
        this.config.workspace.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        this.config.workspace.appendChild(resizedImage);

        resizedImage.src = imageData;
    }
};

ImageUploader.prototype.uploadComplete = function(event, completionCallback) {
    this.progressObject.done++;
    this.progressUpdate(0, 0);
    completionCallback();
    if (this.config.onFileComplete) {
        this.config.onFileComplete(event, this.currentFile);
    }
};

ImageUploader.prototype.progressUpdate = function(itemDone, itemTotal) {
    console.log('Uploaded '+itemDone+' of '+itemTotal);
    this.progressObject.currentItemDone = itemDone;
    this.progressObject.currentItemTotal = itemTotal;
    if (this.config.onProgress) {
        this.config.onProgress(this.progressObject);
    }
};

ImageUploader.prototype.scaleCanvasWithAlgorithm = function(canvas) {
    var scaledCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var scale = this.config.maxWidth / canvas.width;

    scaledCanvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
    scaledCanvas.height = canvas.height * scale;

    var srcImgData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var destImgData = scaledCanvas.getContext('2d').createImageData(scaledCanvas.width, scaledCanvas.height);

    this.applyBilinearInterpolation(srcImgData, destImgData, scale);

    scaledCanvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(destImgData, 0, 0);

    return scaledCanvas;
};

ImageUploader.prototype.getHalfScaleCanvas = function(canvas) {
    var halfCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    halfCanvas.width = canvas.width / 2;
    halfCanvas.height = canvas.height / 2;

    halfCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, halfCanvas.width, halfCanvas.height);

    return halfCanvas;
};

ImageUploader.prototype.applyBilinearInterpolation = function(srcCanvasData, destCanvasData, scale) {
    function inner(f00, f10, f01, f11, x, y) {
        var un_x = 1.0 - x;
        var un_y = 1.0 - y;
        return (f00 * un_x * un_y + f10 * x * un_y + f01 * un_x * y + f11 * x * y);
    }
    var i, j;
    var iyv, iy0, iy1, ixv, ix0, ix1;
    var idxD, idxS00, idxS10, idxS01, idxS11;
    var dx, dy;
    var r, g, b, a;
    for (i = 0; i < destCanvasData.height; ++i) {
        iyv = i / scale;
        iy0 = Math.floor(iyv);
        // Math.ceil can go over bounds
        iy1 = (Math.ceil(iyv) > (srcCanvasData.height - 1) ? (srcCanvasData.height - 1) : Math.ceil(iyv));
        for (j = 0; j < destCanvasData.width; ++j) {
            ixv = j / scale;
            ix0 = Math.floor(ixv);
            // Math.ceil can go over bounds
            ix1 = (Math.ceil(ixv) > (srcCanvasData.width - 1) ? (srcCanvasData.width - 1) : Math.ceil(ixv));
            idxD = (j + destCanvasData.width * i) * 4;
            // matrix to vector indices
            idxS00 = (ix0 + srcCanvasData.width * iy0) * 4;
            idxS10 = (ix1 + srcCanvasData.width * iy0) * 4;
            idxS01 = (ix0 + srcCanvasData.width * iy1) * 4;
            idxS11 = (ix1 + srcCanvasData.width * iy1) * 4;
            // overall coordinates to unit square
            dx = ixv - ix0;
            dy = iyv - iy0;
            // I let the r, g, b, a on purpose for debugging
            r = inner(srcCanvasData.data[idxS00], srcCanvasData.data[idxS10], srcCanvasData.data[idxS01], srcCanvasData.data[idxS11], dx, dy);
            destCanvasData.data[idxD] = r;

            g = inner(srcCanvasData.data[idxS00 + 1], srcCanvasData.data[idxS10 + 1], srcCanvasData.data[idxS01 + 1], srcCanvasData.data[idxS11 + 1], dx, dy);
            destCanvasData.data[idxD + 1] = g;

            b = inner(srcCanvasData.data[idxS00 + 2], srcCanvasData.data[idxS10 + 2], srcCanvasData.data[idxS01 + 2], srcCanvasData.data[idxS11 + 2], dx, dy);
            destCanvasData.data[idxD + 2] = b;

            a = inner(srcCanvasData.data[idxS00 + 3], srcCanvasData.data[idxS10 + 3], srcCanvasData.data[idxS01 + 3], srcCanvasData.data[idxS11 + 3], dx, dy);
            destCanvasData.data[idxD + 3] = a;
        }
    }
};

ImageUploader.prototype.setConfig = function(customConfig) {
    this.config = customConfig;
    this.config.debug = this.config.debug || false;
    this.config.quality = 1.00;
    if (0.00 < customConfig.quality && customConfig.quality <= 1.00) {
        this.config.quality = customConfig.quality;
    }
    if (!this.config.maxWidth) {
        this.config.maxWidth = 480;
    }

    // Create container if none set
    if (!this.config.workspace) {
        this.config.workspace = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(this.config.workspace);
    }
};
  </script>
 <h3>The ImageUploader in all its glory!</h3>
 <input id="fileInputElement1" type="file" name="a">
 <input id="fileInputElement2" type="file" name="b">

 <div id="progress"></div>
 <div id="fileProgress"></div>
 <div id="progressbar"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var uploader = new ImageUploader({
            inputElement : document.getElementById('fileInputElement1'),
            uploadUrl : 'api/image',
            onProgress : function(event) {
                $('#progress').text('Completed '+event.done+' files of '+event.total+' total.');
                $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: (event.done / event.total) * 100 })
            },
            onFileComplete : function(event, file) {
             $('#fileProgress').append('Finished file '+file.fileName+' with response from server '+event.target.status+'<br />');    
            },
            onComplete : function(event) {
                $('#progress').text('Completed all '+event.done+' files!');
                $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: (event.done / event.total) * 100 })
            },
            maxWidth: 480,
            quality: 0.80, 
            //timeout: 5000,
            debug : true
        });
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var uploader = new ImageUploader({
            inputElement : document.getElementById('fileInputElement2'),
            uploadUrl : 'api/image',
            onProgress : function(event) {
                $('#progress').text('Completed '+event.done+' files of '+event.total+' total.');
                $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: (event.done / event.total) * 100 })
            },
            onFileComplete : function(event, file) {
             $('#fileProgress').append('Finished file '+file.fileName+' with response from server '+event.target.status+'<br />');    
            },
            onComplete : function(event) {
                $('#progress').text('Completed all '+event.done+' files!');
                $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: (event.done / event.total) * 100 })
            },
            maxWidth: 480,
            quality: 0.80, 
            //timeout: 5000,
            debug : true
        }); 
    </script>
```

I am not well in JavaScript. But i have to used javascript code for this task. The function of the task is upload image to server before resized.
I find a resized without upload. But can't upload and view it properly.

Problem:
When i click in any image it automatically show in unknown .
And can't find the image temp_location to upload the resized image.

### I need to to show the image in specific

### Find temp location to upload the image.

*NB:* To upload the use 'php' move_uploaded_file() function.

Thanks in advance.